# How I can quickly install MobSF software in macbook

Tags: macos, pip

I am new to macbook. I am trying to install MobSF in macbook, i am getting errors.

When I type the command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --user -upgrade
```

I got below errors:

```
Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: -u
```

Can you please explain what is this error. Suggest some solution.

Comment: Please try posting this in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Stack Overflow is also for questions about programming tools, and `pip` is a programming tool, it installs libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The option is `--upgrade` (double dashes):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --user --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run

`./setup.sh`

See latest docs here: https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/wiki/1.-Documentation